# Dynamic hyperlink a cell to another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have two workbooks in a file (lets call them WorkA and WorkB). Inside WorkA, I have columns A,B,C and inside WorkB, I have D,E,F. Usually, there is a record from WorkA that corresponds to a record(s) in WorkB and that relationship is achieved by columns B and F.

I am trying to define a formula (or anything at this point) where when you click a cell on B, it **searches** for the corresponding cell in F. I know how to define a hyperlink to a specific cell, but I do not know how to define the search functionality and tie it to the hyperlink.

Can somebody point me at what I need to do?

Comment: Write a VBA macro, then create a clickable button and link it to the macro.

Comment: That did occur to me, but I need it to be onClick of the cell, not a separate button

Comment: There are special function names for that, but using those have a tendency to get very much annoying if you have the slightest error (starting with the type matching 'ouch, didn't think of that') in your functions. Right now I don't remember anything to look for, to find an example. I have avoided these as the plague.